# How to make curve using UIBezierPath?

Tags: swift, swift3, core-graphics, uibezierpath

How to draw curve as shown in image using UIBezierPath?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @CivFan I tried a lot but no success. I tried to use arc method of UIBezier path.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise a path.

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGFloat xPos = 100.0;
CGFloat yPos = 50.0;
CGFloat width = 200;
CGFloat height = 200;

CGPoint controlPoint = CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0);

// Set the starting point of the shape.
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)];
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos, width)];

// Draw the lines.
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height)];

//Add your arc here
[aPath addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos, height) controlPoint1:controlPoint controlPoint2:CGPointZero]

[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)];

//Close the Path
[aPath closePath];
```

Try the above code. It's not the tested code, I'm not at my System. By adjusting the control Point, you can increase the radius of the arc.